# Correct way to store MD5 hashes in an Elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch for creating a custom search API. I need to store MD5 hashes in one of the indices. I also need the field to be searchable. How should I index/analyze the field so that the search is performant enough?
I need the query to work fast enough to support autocomplete.

So far I've mapped the field as text only.
I'm using 'match_phrase_prefix' query, which works well as of now. However, I'm worried if the performance would decrease as more and more docs are indexed.
I also wanted to use 'completion' suggest mapping, but that restricts us from filtering on any other field. Hence, it won't work.
I also planned to use 'edge_ngram' analyzer with a low min_gram and a high max_gram value. Noticed that the index size goes up rapidly with that mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MD5 hashes are composed of a single token you don't need to use `match_phrase_prefix` but simply `prefix`. Try it out.

Also note that you can definitely use completion and filtering by using the [context suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html) instead of the completion suggester. However, granted, you can only provide a category context or a geo context, no date ranges or other more evolved filters/contexts.

If you're always searching for exact MD5, I'd use the `keyword` type.
However, if you're searching for MD5 prefixes (+ some filters in some cases), then `text` with the proper edge-ngram analyzer will work better, even though your index size will grow.

Without knowing more about your use case, this is pretty much all that can be said.

Comment: Great! I think edge-ngram is the way. Thanks!

Comment: There's also a good resource worth reading that compares the three approaches (prefix, edge-ngram and completion) here: https://medium.com/@mourjo_sen/a-detailed-comparison-between-autocompletion-strategies-in-elasticsearch-66cb9e9c62c4

Comment: Thanks! A feedback after around 2 weeks of asking the question, I went with edge-ngram, the performance is spot on.